# iterating through MSBuild output in batch - MSB1008: Only one project can be specified

Tags: loops, batch-file, msbuild

I'm attempting to do some custom processing out our build output after our build has completed.

Usually we have a batch file which does the following:

```
... do stuff first ...

msbuild /m /p:Configuration=Release "C:\Path\To\File\No\Whitespace\MySolution.sln"

... do more stuff...
```

and this works.

Now trying to process the output, I've done the following

```
... do stuff first ...

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`msbuild /m /p:Configuration=Release "C:\Path\To\File\No\Whitespace\MySolution.sln"`) DO (
  ECHO %%F
)

ENDLOCAL

... do more stuff ...
```

However this outputs the following:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: C:\Path\To\File\No\Whitespace\MySolution.sln
For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

I've tried removing the quotes from the path as indicated in other SO answers, but no luck. How can I successfully run msbuild and loop through the output?

Comment: If I remove the build flags `/m /p:Configuration=Release`, the build does run, so it appears to be an issue passing in these arguments

Comment: We do not use backticks to issue commands, we use quotes.. also, `usebackq` and `tokens` are not needed here. `FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('msbuild /m /p:Configuration=Release "C:\Path\To\File\No\Whitespace\MySolution.sln"') do echo %%F` and lastly, __unless__ you use it elsewhere in the batch file, `delayedexpansion` is not needed here.

Comment: Build flags `/m /p:Configuration^=Release`. The `=` needs to be escaped.